# Desactivar slide right cerrar app en Android Wear

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-wear

Estoy realizando pruebas en Android Wear, algunas apps desactivan el gesto "slide-right" para cerrar la app, haciendo que solo se pueda cerrar con pulsación larga o bien botón físico.

¿Cómo desactivar el gesto slide de cerrar app en Android Wear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define el tema definido a tu Activity con la propiedad `android:windowSwipeToDismiss` con valor false :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Buenas @Elenasys tambien he encontrado estableciendo en la activity @style/Theme.Wearable.Modal Pero hereda tema oscuro por defecto

Comment: @Webserveis he tenido poca experiencia con Wear, te puedo comentar que use lo que indicas  @style/Theme.Wearable.Modal pero en mi caso no me funciono, veo que se usa pero tal vez existe algb tipo de restriccion.